# Mixed Integer formulation using macro/excel based formulae

Tags: excel, vba

I have been creating formulations manually in excel. The process becomes quite time consuming if the number of variables is large. Is there any inbuilt function in Excel that I can use effectively to create the formulation? I tried to write a macro to generate this formulation but no success yet. I can share it if required.

An example of one such constraint is:

```
Cik - Cpk + Dipk - Tijk >= 0
```

where
i = 1, 2,...,8
'p' not equal to 'i' and it holds values 1, 2,...,8
k = 1, 2,...,8
j = 64 values stored in A1:A64 (total combinations of i and k = 8*8 =64 e.g. 11, 12 ....88)

When I generate the formulation manually and with a little bit of excel drag cell help, it looks like this-

```
C11-C21+D121-T171>=0    (7 is stored in cell A1)  
C11-C31+D131-T171>=0  
.  
.  
C11-C81+D141-T171>=0  
C21-C11+D211-T231>=0  
C21-C31+D231-T231>=0  
.  
.  
C21-C81+D241-T231>=0  
.  
.  
.  
.  
C12-C22+D122-T152>=0  
C12-C32+D132-T152>=0  
.  
.  
.  

C88-C78+D878-T838>=0 etc.
```

Comment: I don't understand how 171 is the first subscript (index) for T.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell from your question what you want to do with these formulas but to get you going the following will give you a list of all the permutations. It's not the quickest way but the code should be obvious enough for you to adjust as you need.

This will output them all to `Sheet1`, so make sure you've saved anything on that sheet before running this or run it in a new workbook. Uncomment the formula line if you actually want the cell references but I haven't disabled auto-calculation so it'll take longer to run.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim ik As Integer
Dim pk As Integer
Dim ipk As Integer
Dim ji As Integer
Dim jk As Integer
Dim ijk As Integer
Dim r As Long
Dim formulaText As String

r = 0
For i = 1 To 8
    For p = 1 To 8
        If p <> i Then
            For k = 1 To 8
                ik = i * 10 + k
                pk = p * 10 + k
                ipk = i * 100 + pk
                For ji = 1 To 8
                    For jk = 1 To 8
                        r = r + 1
                        ijk = i * 100 + ji * 10 + jk
                        formulaText = "C" & CStr(ik) & "-C" & CStr(pk) & "+D" & CStr(ipk) & "-T" & CStr(ijk)
                        Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value = formulaText
                        'Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Formula = "=" & formulaText
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
```